# maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0 is work with laravel 10?

Tags: excel, laravel

I am using Laravel 10 and importing file using maatwebsite/excel": "~3.1" package
so  maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0" is works with laravel 10 or not ?

Comment: Why don't you just install the package and check? It would be faster than waiting for an answer.

Comment: i checked but it has given some kind of error so for better knowledge i asked it.

Answer (score 0):

`composer require maatwebsite/excel:^2.1 --ignore-platform-reqs` this will not work with laravel 10

```php
  Problem 1
    - maatwebsite/excel[v2.1.0, ..., v2.1.3] require illuminate/cache 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.* -> found illuminate/cache[v5.0.0, ..., v5.2.45] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - maatwebsite/excel[2.1.4, ..., 2.1.9] require illuminate/cache 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.* -> found illuminate/cache[v5.0.0, ..., v5.3.23] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - maatwebsite/excel[2.1.10, ..., 2.1.20] require illuminate/cache 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.* -> found illuminate/cache[v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.36] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - maatwebsite/excel[2.1.21, ..., 2.1.24] require illuminate/cache 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.* -> found illuminate/cache[v5.0.0, ..., v5.5.44] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - maatwebsite/excel[2.1.25, ..., 2.1.29] require illuminate/cache 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.*|5.6.* -> found illuminate/cache[v5.0.0, ..., v5.6.39] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - maatwebsite/excel 2.1.30 requires illuminate/cache ^5.0 -> found illuminate/cache[v5.0.0, ..., v5.8.36] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - Root composer.json requires maatwebsite/excel ^2.1 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[v2.1.0, ..., 2.1.30].
```